# Parsing incomplete json array

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have downloaded 5MB of a very large json file. From this, I need to be able to load that 5MB to generate a preview of the json file. However, the file will probably be incomplete. Here's an example of what it may look like:

```
[{
    "first": "bob",
    "address": {
        "street": 13301,
        "zip": 1920
    }
}, {
    "first": "sarah",
    "address": {
        "street": 13301,
        "zip": 1920
    }
}, {"first" : "tom"
```

From here, I'd like to "rebuild it" so that it can parse the first two objects (and ignore the third).

Is there a json parser that can `infer` or cut off the end of the string to make it parsable? Or perhaps to 'stream' the parsing of the json array, so that when it fails on the last object, I can exit the loop? If not, how could the above be accomplished?

Comment: That's such a broken API. I don't think it's possible to parse an arbitrary snippet of JSON. It could have any nested structure that just gets cut off.

Comment: If it's trivial (as in your example), just do it by hand. If it's not, um...err....

Comment: This is just a bad recommend. You can use pandas to read json and then for preview df.head(2).to_json(orient='records')

Comment: seems that you don't have a lot of luck with input formats :)

Comment: What's the reason you want to include the first two "objects" (I suppose you mean the two outermost dicts) but not the third? What makes the json incomplete is a missing `}]`, so by only considering the json format there's no reason to exclude the `{"first": "tom"}`. The exact criteria for where to crop the string are crucial for developing an algorithm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your data will always look somewhat similar, you could do something like this:

```
import json

json_string = """[{
    "first": "bob",
    "address": {
        "street": 13301,
        "zip": 1920
    }
}, {
    "first": "sarah",
    "address": {
        "street": 13301,
        "zip": 1920
    }
}, {"first" : "tom"
"""

while True:
    if not json_string:
        raise ValueError("Couldn't fix JSON")
    try:
        data = json.loads(json_string + "]")
    except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
        json_string = json_string[:-1]
        continue
    break

print(data)
```

This assumes that the data is a list of dicts. Step by step, the last character is removed and a missing `]` appended. If the new string can be interpreted as JSON, the infinite loop breaks. Otherwise the next character is removed and so on. If there are no characters left `ValueError("Couldn't fix JSON")` is raised.

For the above example, it prints:

```
[{'first': 'bob', 'address': {'zip': 1920, 'street': 13301}}, {'first': 'sarah', 'address': {'zip': 1920, 'street': 13301}}]
```

Comment: oh I like that simple approach.

Answer (score 1):

For the specific structure in the example we can walk through the string and track occurrences of curly brackets and their closing counterparts. If at the end one or more curly brackets remain unmatched, we know that this indicates an incomplete object. We can then strip any intermediate characters such as commas or whitespace and close the resulting string with a square bracket.

This method ensures that the string is only parsed twice, one time manually and one time by the JSON parser, which might be advantageous for large text files (with incomplete objects consisting of many characters).

```
brackets = []
for i, c in enumerate(string):
    if c == '{':
        brackets.append(i)
    elif c == '}':
        brackets.pop()

if brackets:
    string = string[:brackets[0]].rstrip(', \n')

if not string.endswith(']'):
    string += ']'
```

Comment: thanks for this answer. As a generalization to the above, how could you 'complete' something more general, such as [this](https://hastebin.com/uducikutak.json) ?

Comment: @David542 Actually the algorithm is not *completing* but *reducing* the json to its valid parts and closing it with the missing brackets. In that sense the specific structure you linked is not more general, it is just a different structure (with different bracketing). Here you can define an offset within the string and then use the same procedure as above: `marker = '"data": ['; offset = string.index(marker) + len(marker)`. You'll need to close the resulting string with `]}]}}` instead. If you want to be independent of the structure you'll need to write your own custom json parser.