# How to extract incomplete Python objects from string

Tags: python, regex, list, dictionary, parsing

I am attempting to extract valid Python-parsable objects, such as dictionaries and lists, from strings. For example, from the string `"[{'a' : 1, 'b' : 2}]"`, the script will extract `[{'a' : 1, 'b' : 2}]` since the `{}` and `[]` denote completed Python objects.

However, when the string output is incomplete, such as `"[{'a' : 1, 'b' : 2}, {'a' : 1'}]"`, I only attempt to extract `{'a' : 1, 'b' : 2}` and place it into a list `[{'a' : 1, 'b' : 2}]`, as the second Python object is not yet complete and therefore must be left out.

I tried to write a regex pattern to match completed `{}` or `[]`, it works for simple output but failing on nested list or dict.

Code:

```
import re 

def match_dict_list(string): 
    pattern = r"\[?\{[^\}\]]*\}\]?|\[?\[[^\]\[]*\]\]?"
    matches = re.findall(pattern, string)
    return matches
```

But it's failing on `"""[[1, 2, 3], [11, 12, 21]"""` because it's matching `[[1, 2, 3], [11, 12, 21]` while the expected output is only  `[1, 2, 3], [11, 12, 21]` and put it in list `[ [[1, 2, 3], [11, 12, 21] ]`

Some test cases

- Case 1: `"[{'a' : 1, 'b' : 2}, {'a' : 1'"`

  Expected output: `[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}]`
- Case 2: `'[[1, 2, 3], [11, 12, 21]'`

  Expected output: `[[1, 2, 3], [11, 12, 21]]`
- Case 3: `"""[{'a': [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}], 'b': [{'a':"""`

  Expected output: `[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}]`

I am getting the output from APIs but can't do anything from their side; sometimes, the server output is complete, and sometimes, it's incomplete.

I also tried the updated pattern : `\[?\{[^\}\]]*\}\]?|\[[^\]\[]*\]|\[\[[^\]\[]*\]\]` but it's failing on third case. what is the best option to solve this kind of issue?

I can't use `ast.literal_eval` because as I mentioned above the string output is incomplete such as `" [ { 'a' : 1 } , {'b' : "`.

Comment: Why you got incomplete 'objects' ?

Comment: WRT edit: What if you iterate over all substrings, running `ast.literal_eval` on all of them and discard the ones that throw SyntaxError or similar?

Comment: Why do you need this?  Maybe there's a better solution for your intended goal.

Comment: There is a reason parsers don't try to fix "obvious" syntax errors. Why are you trying to do so?

Comment: Also, it's impossible to do this with regex, due to arbitrarily-deeply-nested expressions being possible.

Comment: Re: `I am getting the output from APIs but can't do anything from their side; sometimes, the server output is complete, and sometimes, it's incomplete.`, APIs should serialize data using a format like JSON, not python reprs (incomplete, to boot).  If you are able to provide feedback to the owner of the API, you should make them fix their output.

Comment: On closer inspection, this looks an awful lot more like JSON than python objects. Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53937434/parsing-incomplete-json-array and the answers might be helpful

Comment: *`"[{'a' : 1, 'b' : 2}, {'a' : 1'}]"`, I only attempt to extract `{'a' : 1, 'b' : 2}` [...], as the second Python object is not yet complete and therefore must be left out.* - how that could become complete, ever, with a pair-less quotation mark inside, and the closing curly brace and bracket already in place? It's not incomplete, but broken.

Answer (score 0):

> *I can't use `ast.literal_eval` because as I mentioned above the string output is incomplete such as `" [ { 'a' : 1 } , {'b' : "`*

But you *can* iteratively try to apply `ast.literal_eval` after slicing off the last character and closing the first bracket <sub>[similarly to how `json.loads` was used in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53937551/6146136) suggested in [@mous](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16435355/mous)'s comment]</sub>.

```py
import ast

def eval_brokenLiteral(litStr:str, defaultVal=None, printError=True):
    try: return ast.literal_eval(litStr)
    except SyntaxError as se: evalError = se 
    # litStr = litStr[:getattr(evalError, 'offset', len(litStr))]

    bracketPairs = {'{': '}', '[': ']'}
    closers, curCloser = [], ''
    for c in ''.join(litStr.split()):
        if c not in bracketPairs: break
        curCloser = bracketPairs[c] + curCloser
        closers.append(curCloser)

    for closer in closers:
        subStr = litStr.strip() 
        while subStr[1:]:
            try: return ast.literal_eval(subStr + closer)
            except SyntaxError: subStr = subStr[:-1].strip()

    if printError: print(repr(evalError))
    return defaultVal
```

[If it can't find a valid literal, it will return `None` unless some other `defaultVal` is specified.]

---

#### Tests:

```py
testCases = [
    "[{'a' : 1, 'b' : 2}, {'a' : 1'}]",
    '[[1, 2, 3], [11, 12, 21]',
    """[{'a': [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}], 'b': [{'a':"""
]
for ti, tc in enumerate(testCases, 1):
    print(f'Case {ti}: {repr(tc)}\n  -  ----> ', end='')
    op = eval_brokenLiteral(tc)
    print(f'Output ---> {repr(op)}' if op else '', '\n\n---\n')
```

> <sub>Case 1: *`"[{'a' : 1, 'b' : 2}, {'a' : 1'}]"`*</sub>
>
> - ----> Output ---> <kbd>**`[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}]`**</kbd>
>
> ---
>
> <sub>Case 2: *`'[[1, 2, 3], [11, 12, 21]'`*</sub>
>
> - ----> Output ---> <kbd>**`[[1, 2, 3], [11, 12, 21]]`**</kbd>
>
> ---
>
> <sub>Case 3: *`"[{'a': [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}], 'b': [{'a':"`*</sub>
>
> - ----> Output ---> <kbd>**`[{'a': [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}]}]`**</kbd>
>
> ---